# Picking priors in Bayesian MCMC linear regression

Tags: regression, bayesian

Let me preface this by saying that I am an applied statistician teaching myself Bayesian regression.  If we can do this without Greek letters that would be great.

Suppose I am modeling a continuous outcome on some predictor. We'll assume a jeffrey's prior for the variance.  Now I need a prior for my predictor and the constant.  Essentially what I am doing is setting up a distribution that the values for the parameters (the coefficients for the constant and predictor) will be drawn from, correct?

Assuming I want informative priors, my immediate inclination is to go with a normal prior.  I set the mean to my "best guess" of what the effect of the predictor ought to be and then set the variance.  I like the normal distribution because it is essentially favoring values near my guess while discounting those far from it (i.e. the tails) and discounting them in a symmetrical way.  I'm also specifically wondering if I can make use of the standard deviation to characterize my confidence in my guess.  An example will illustrate.

I get that larger variances mean less weight assigned to the prior belief.  However, I am curious if I can interpret this in terms of standard deviations.  For example, if I believe the effect will be 5, I set the mean at 5.  Let's say I'm 95% confident that the effect will be between 15 and -5.  This would call for a standard deviation of 5 so I'd set the variance at 25.  Is this a proper way to describe my confidence in the prior?

As another example, if I were absolutely positive that the effect was going to be somewhere between -10 and 20 I would use a uniform prior ranging from -10 - 20, correct?  Am I also correct in assuming that all this is true regardless of the actual distribution of the independent variable (i.e. it could be continuous or dichotomous)?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, yes. Normal priors are common and your approach to selecting the s.d./variance is perfectly reasonable. I'd recommend reading any of Andrew Gelman's stuff about prior distributions. His book Bayesian Data Analysis is a very good and approachable resource for (almost) all things Bayesian.

> Essentially what I am doing is setting up a distribution that the values for the parameters (the coefficients for the constant and predictor) will be drawn from, correct?

In a sense, yes, but I don't think this is the best way to think of priors. Priors are there to dampen/accentuate the likelihood in certain regions of parameter space, i.e. to *weight* the likelihood in some way.

If we choose improper uniform priors (i.e. completely uninformative), the posterior distribution is just a normalised likelihood, which is very sensitive to the data. The mode of this distribution is the estimate you would get from running any common linear regression procedure (`lm` in R for example).

This is fine if we have complete faith in our data -- we're sure it reflects the population distribution pretty well.

If we have reason to be suspicious of the data, it makes sense to include a prior. The effect of this is that if the data happen to result in lots of likelihood at some unreasonable parameter value, our prior should cancel it out by attaching a very small weight to that value; remember we multiply the prior and the likelihood (pointwise) to get the posterior distribution.

So you aren't really drawing parameter values from the prior, rather you're expressing a restriction on the parameter values you're willing to accept as reasonable by weighting the likelihood. As a very loose approximation, we're just modifying the likelihood before we run `lm` to find its maximum to make sure our estimates don't come out as being unreasonable/at odds with our prior understanding of the process.